# Tabbar Bar changes once user clicks

Tags: ios, tabbar

I have toolbar implemented in my application. Whenever user clicks on the tabbar, tabbar's alpha value changes. Is there a way to fix it ? Why does it give this error. Before and after click on the tabbar figures attached

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not the tab bar that's changing, but rather the view beneath it. Tab bars in iOS 7 are typically semi-transparent, so the view controller's view influences its appearance.

Consider setting the tab bar's `translucent` property to NO to make the bar opaque.

Comment: Background is the same for all other viewcontrollers

Comment: @casillas Look at the size of the view for each view controller, then. One may be shorter than it needs to be, or its constraints may not be set properly, resulting in empty space under the tab bar.

Comment: I have got it.Thanks a lot. I am going to vote your answer as  right answer.